# How do you get the file path of an <input> file?

Tags: javascript, post

I'm trying to use the Axios POST method to upload a  file to Pinata IPFS:

FRONT-END:

```
<body>
  <input type="file" id="file-upload" ></input>
  <script> let file = document.getElementById("file-upload").value;</script>
</body>
```

FILE GETS SENT TO BACKEND THROUGH SOCKET.IO:

```
pin = (pinataApiKey, pinataSecretApiKey, file) => {
  url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS`;

  const data = new FormData();

  data.append("file", fs.createReadStream(`${file}`));

  return axios.post(url, data, {
    maxBodyLength: "Infinity",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
      pinata_api_key: pinataApiKey,
      pinata_secret_api_key: pinataSecretApiKey,
    },
  });
};
```

pin() only works when I use a local file path (i.e. C:/Users/anon/Desktop/project/untitled.png). If I try to use file.value (whose path is "C:\fakepath\testImage.jpeg"), the code doesn't work. I need the actual path of the uploaded file.

Comment: You cannot get the actual path on the client. Browsers deliberately obfuscate the paths. All you can rely on is the file name.

Comment: The sending file to backend through socket.io code is missing

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you log file??

Perhaps you need to put this:

```
let file = document.getElementById("file-upload").value;
```

inside your js file:

And probably the best thing is to do some validations before the file is uploaded.

Comment: The actual value of "file" is "C:\fakepath\testImage.jpeg." I searched this in chrome and got an "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND," so clearly the file path is the problem. I'm not sure how else to extract the file from <input>, though.